# Get count of common field among the same records, SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume we have the following records:

| Id | Column A | Column B | Column C | Common |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | 12 |
| 2 | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | 13 |
| 3 | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | 08 |
| 4 | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | 10 |
| 5 | Value4 | Value5 | Value6 | 18 |
| 6 | Value4 | Value5 | Value6 | 22 |
| 7 | Value4 | Value5 | Value6 | 37 |

How can we get the following result

| Id | Column A | Column B | Column C | CommonCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | 4 |
| 5 | Value4 | Value5 | Value6 | 3 |

I wrote this query:

```sql
SELECT 
    jr.*,
    CommonCount = (SELECT COUNT(1)
                   FROM la.JudicialReference AS jr1
                   WHERE ((jr.ColumnA = jr1.ColumnA) 
                          OR ISNULL(jr.ColumnA, jr1.ColumnA) IS NULL)
                     AND ((jr.ColumnB = jr1.ColumnB) 
                          OR ISNULL(jr.ColumnB, jr1.ColumnB) IS NULL) 
                     AND ((jr.ColumnC = jr1.ColumnC) 
                          OR ISNULL(jr.ColumnC, jr1.ColumnC) IS NULL))
FROM 
    la.JudicialReference AS jr
```

But it doesn't get me the first Id and I'm looking for a better query to save IO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply

```
SELECT MIN(ID), ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, COUNT(*)
FROM la.JudicialReference
GROUP BY ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC
```

Optionally with `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`